# Is ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Object>> Thread safe?

Tags: java, arraylist, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent

This is how I have defined a `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Object>> all_payloads = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Object>>();
```

I understand that there the blocking operation works only when writing or removing from the `ConcurrentHashMap`, but will this lock extend to the values which are of `ArrayList` type too?

For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < all_payloads.get(0).size(); i++) {
        if(all_payloads.get(0).get(i).getBucketNumberCollector() == this.bucket_no) {
            currentPayload = all_payloads.get(0).remove(i);
            currentPayload.setCollector(collector);
            all_payloads.get(1).add(currentPayload);
            break;
        }
    }
```

In the above snippet, I am only using the `get​(Object key)` method to modify the value associated with that key - which in this case is of type `ArrayList`.

Will the above snippet be thread-safe? If not then what can be done to make it so?

Comment: Are there other entries except `0` and `1` ? If not, two separate variables may make more sense than stuffing them into a map.

Comment: @Thilo Yes there are, I just put in ```0``` and ```1``` to hide some more unrelated logic to calculate the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. An `ArrayList` is an `ArrayList`, regardless of where you put it. The `ConcurrentHashMap`'s synchronization extends only to the `get` operation, and from there on, if multiple threads can execute the same piece of code concurrently, you'd need an additional mechanism to protect it.

```java
List<Object> myList = all_payloads.get(0);
synchronized (myList) {
    // code that uses myList
```

Comment: So, as per your suggestion, would this work?
https://codeshare.io/G8xyde

Answer (score 2):

Even if `ArrayList` was thread-safe (which it is not), you have four different `all_payloads.get` calls in that snippet, and even if those are individually thread-safe, the combination of them is not (the calls can be interleaved in funky ways in the presence of concurrency).